# LNK2019 Linking error on Windows, works fine on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, windows-ce, linker-errors

I am porting large project from Linux to WinCE. Currently facing problem of linking error LNK2019. 
AS I can see from the error it is because of the overloaded static function is not defined, only declaration. E.g:

```
template<bool taValue>
struct type
{
};

typedef type<true> MTrue;
typedef type<false> MFalse;

    static int getData(int i, MTrue) { return 2; }
    static int getData(int i, MFalse);
```

This is just a sample of code and not exact scenario.

The compilation is working well for Linux but it is falling linking time for WinCE. If I comment out the overloaded undefined function in Linux, then I can see same set of linking error in Linux as well.

I am not sure, why this is happening this case?
Is there any compiler option which can avoid this linking error in case of Linux?
Note: compiler gcc/g++ 4.2.2 and cmake version 3.2.2

Comment: Which error exactly?

Comment: @Drop LNK2019 error, as error log is bigger and having lots of template argument, I cannot paste full error. But the route cause is definition for static function is not available still it compiles fine for Linux.

Comment: @swapnil Yes, we posses the telepathic powers of knowing, just knowing, what the error is saying, **exactly**, on your machine, without you pasting it.

Comment: @swapnil If you can't paste the exact error, manufacture [mcve] that's functionally similar to your original code, but still reproduces the error, and paste that.

Comment: Can you paste one of the errors and the code fragment that the error message refers to?

Comment: Is there content for the 2nd `getData` function?  It looks like a static declaration, so the linker will not show any content (actually, the linker will be looking for the content, but won't find any and thus generate a warning or error message).